# Lua execution in Redis - Atomicity & Scale?

Tags: lua, redis

I have some keys in Redis `<K,V>` where V is a comma separated string of sub strings `V: <v1,v2,v3,...,vn>`.

Until now I was simply setting keys by using a transaction in Jedis (Redis API in Java). But a new requirement needs me to perform some operations on the existing keys. So I have two options:

1. Retrieve Keys, Perform Operations, Set keys
2. Code the operations in Lua and pass the file along with keys as arguments.

Option 2 seems faster as it will save a round trip but I have the following considerations:

1. What if Lua execution fails in between at Redis, say after n keys. (May be an issue with script or Redis). Does Redis ensure consistency? In option 1, I could abort writing and prevent inconsistent state.
2. Lua script as I understand takes keys as arguments. However I need to operate on 10 million keys. Is Lua fine with such a huge argument list?

**My Solution**

Since as said by the answer below none of them are a feasible choice. I wrote my own Redis command in C and compiled the source. So now I will call

```
redis-cli> MyCommand K V
```

For each `<K,V>` in pipeline. I followed the tutorial here - [Hacking Redis](http://www.starkiller.net/2013/05/02/hacking-redis-adding-a-command/). However it might not be adequate and require one to browse and understand some code by yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrt #1 - a Lua script is atomic but it does **not** provide this type of consistency assurance. In case a script fails, its updates will **not** be rolled back by Redis automatically. There is a proposal to improve this behavior but it is yet to be accepted into Redis (see Josiah Carlson's blog here: http://www.dr-josiah.com/2015/07/transactions-in-redis.html)

wrt #2 - I don't know if such a huge list will go smoothly or not but if you need it you're probably using it wrong ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess my hunch was correct regarding consistency. I need to edit values for 10 million keys. However I have written my own custom function in C and plugged into Redis. For now It is working good. 

PS: That was a nice blog. Thanks for citing. I am following it.

Comment: Dr. Carlson is one of the community's corner stones and his blog is indeed nice (although the Thorium reactor thingy is a bit far fetched imo) - I dedicated today's Virtual Moka Cup to him: https://redislabs.com/redis-watch-archive/52 ;)